# October CMS - Deploying System Updates

Tags: octobercms

When I am in my dev environment and run `php artisan october:update` it updates the cms files to their latest version and runs some DB updates.

The file changes are easy enough to deploy, but what about any Database changes the system update made? I don't see a migration file or anything created that would make sure the same changes happened when I deploy to production.

Is the only way to run `php artisan october:update` again in production? That seems risky as you could accidentally grab a newer version than you had tested.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any new migrations to be run (either from October or new / updated plugins), then running `php artisan october:up` will run them.

You can use that command instead in your production environment to avoid accidentally updating your live environment. Although, ideally you'd be using a staging environment that would run these commands and then migrate just the final results over to production (i.e. the verified migrated database and files in one fell swoop instead of running migrations on production).

Comment: If I upgrade october locally and then push up the file changes to staging/prod and run `php artisan october:up` it does not update the DB. I still see the old version set in the DB table and in the admin dashboard. It only works if I run the update in every envornment individually or if I push my DB from staging to prod as you said. Seems flawed that in October a text change in a page would require a code deployment (to push the files/db from staging).

Comment: All migrations of the Octobercms core are in: ```modules/backend/database/migrations``` , ```modules/cms/database/migrations``` and ```modules/system/database/migrations```. Are you sure you have pushed those folders also to the other server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a Plugin versioning file (http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/updates#version-file)

Migrations are defined in that file and those will be executed on a `php artisan october:up`.

**Whoops** I misread your question. My answer is about Plugins and not about the core updates.